# How is $\ln(\sin 2x)^{\ln x} = \ln x \cdot \sin 2x$?

Tags: logarithms

In my textbook, there's something like:

$$\ln(\sin 2x)^{\ln x} = \ln x \cdot \sin 2x$$

I thought it should be

$$\ln x\cdot \ln(\sin 2x).$$

Comment: $\ln(a^b)=b\ln a$.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, $\ln\left((\sin2x)^{\ln x}\right)=(\ln x)\cdot \ln (\sin 2x)$. Do you have more context?

Comment: Hmm ... but according to the book, notice the 2nd $ln$ is missing. $ln(sin2x)$ is just $sin2x$. As for more context, this is actually to differenciate $sin2x^{lnx}$. This is the 1st step when $ln$ is taken on both sides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the textbook means to imply that 
$$\ln\left[(\sin 2x)^{\ln x}\right]=(\ln x) \cdot \sin 2x,\quad\;\;\text{ }$$
then **it is in error**, because in actuality it is as you say it is:
$$\ln\left[(\sin 2x)^{\ln x}\right]=(\ln x)\cdot \ln(\sin2x).$$
If the rest of the derivation proceeds from this folly, it is completely wrong.

Comment: So the crucial question is, what's the rest of the derivation? If the argument proceeds as if the author(s) had written the right thing, then it's just a typo. If the argument seriously makes use of $\log x\sin2x$, then, as anon suggests, it's hard to imagine anything but nonsense resulting. So: what does the book do next? For that matter, what book is it? what page?

Comment: Oh ... icic, I looked into the textbook errata and discovered its indeed an error ... caused me so much confusion :)